# Is there a template XCode project I can use for making an iOS app that just shows a webpage?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I want to make an iPhone/iOS app that, when opened, simply launches a UIWebView with a particular page and does nothing else. Is there a template XCode project I can use to help accelerate the process for me a little?

Comment: So you basically want to create an app that gets rejected because it violates rule 2.12 of the [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Xcode does not provide such a template. You can, however, use the "Single View Application" template and it should be pretty easy to do with Storyboards.

Here's a tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGPJeYxWr3Y

Answer (score 1):

There is no template. But you can just create a new project "Single View Application". Then set in Interface Builder your view to a UIWebView and add some lines to load your required website, e.g. viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView]; 
[webView release];
```

put this in the viewDidLoad of your single view applications view controller and you have it.. :)

Comment: Need to change `self addSubview:...` to `self.view addSubview:...`

Answer (score 1):

There is a shell app for the same on GITHub. 
https://github.com/endymion/iOS-HTML5-Shell-App/

But as the author says, do the world a favor and don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a template, but you could just drop this into your project and use it. It's a drop in UIWebView. http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/web-browser-view-controller